# Issue when sorting items in Outlook folder

Tags: delphi, automation, outlook

I am calling sort on an Outlook folder, trying to **sort by received time**.  However when the folder contains a non-email item (*a `Task`*), I get an error saying that the `ReceivedTime` property does not exists.

```
oFolderItems := oFolder.Items;
oFolderItems.sort('ReceivedTime',2);  //2 = Descending
```

The reason for the sorting is that for some users there can be thousands of emails in the folder I am accessing, and they only want to see the x number of latest one.

Any tips on how to avoid the non-email items?

Comment: How is oFolder defined; what Outllok object is it?

Comment: oFolder is normally the inbox folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**DASL Filter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147579%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to restrict the items shown in a given `View` or `Items` collection. For filtering to just mail messages, you can use the [**Message Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171490%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property (*MAPI name `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS`*) and restrict it to just [`IPM.Note`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176446%28v=office.12%29.aspx). The [`_Items.Restrict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.restrict.aspx) method will help you apply the DASL filter.

```
string messageClassFilter = "@SQL=" + "\"" + "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x001a001e" + "\"" + " LIKE 'IPM.Note%'";
oFolderItems := oFolder.Items.Restrict(messageClassFilter); // filter by Message Class
oFolderItems.sort('ReceivedTime',2);  //2 = Descending
```